# Which way is faster? What exactly is happening, what are we not seeing?

Tags: c++, performance, memory

I think this method is faster, because there are 2 pointers, each of which goes on its own piece of memory without interruptions, but maybe the compiler converts the second option as well? And does the compiler add an additional variable for the condition (after all, this is a constant), or does it re-calculate the condition each time?

```
matrix(const matrix<T> &a)
    {
        this->lenght = a.lenght;
        this->height = a.height;

        this->container = new T[this->lenght * this->height];

        T* adres_A = a.container;
        T* adres_this = this->container;
        for (; adres_this < (this->container + this->lenght * this->height); adres_this++, adres_A++)
            {               
                adres_this[0] = adres_A[0];
            }
    }
```

Or

```
matrix(const matrix<T> &a)
    {
        this->lenght = a.lenght;
        this->height = a.height;

        this->container = new T[this->lenght * this->height];

        for (int i = 0; i < this->lenght * this->height; i++)
        {
            this->container[i] = a.container[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. Inspect the generated assembly code to know what really is your compiler doing with your code. `the compiler` If it's "the compiler", then which compiler is it? what compiler version? and which compiler options are you using?

Comment: Why do you use `adres_this[0]` and `adres_A[0]` instead of `*adres_this` resp. `*adres_A`?

Comment: You can always compare what machine code the different compilers create for two different approaches, e.g. by using [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: Independent to your question. The std library ships with an `<algorithm>` header that does various common tasks, and exists to be used. And there you have e.g. [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) that allow you to copy the contents from one container to another. And using an `std::vector<T>` instead of `new T` will also make many things easier and less error prone.

Comment: I use adres[0] instead *adres becouse was an error but now i fix it to *

Comment: "They do different things" no, they do the same things. I dont know where its different

Comment: @George the two pointers `adres_this` and `adres_A`  are moved in each iteration of the loop (`adres_this++, adres_A++`). So the first example does not only copy the element that referees to the element at index `0` of the original pointer.

Comment: `adres_this[0] = adres_A[0];` is *defined* to be equivalent to `*(adres_this + 0) = *(adres_A + 0);` What error did you get with `*adres_this = *adres_A`?

Comment: "What error did you get with" i was declared address variables at the beginning of the loop as for( T* adres = .... ; ) and dont know why but compiler say its not T*, and i write it before loop now.

Comment: That's not what I asked. And the reason that you can't `a.container++` is that it is a `T * const` in this context

Answer (score 0):

> I think this method is faster because there are 2 pointers, each of which goes on its own piece of memory without interruptions

That does not mean that the compiler will use that approach in the final code. With the code you write, you describe your intent on what you want to do. Based on that description and the guarantees and requirements the specification of the language defines the compiler is free to generate the machine code in any way, as long as it is according to the requirements of the language specification.

So whether your first or second code is faster depends on how well the compiler can interpret your code, and therefore optimize it. And that depends on the compiler you use and the version.

And it also depends on what pre assumptions a compiler can make about the code. It might be that the compiler is able to detect that loop unfolding can be done in certain situations which clang 10 did in my test for your first example, or that utilizing `memcopy` is possible as it did for the second example. And for my particular test, the second example would result in faster code in `clang`. (which does not mean that this will always be the case).

In general, the first step for writing efficient code is to utilize what the std library provides, the compiler know these types and function and their boundary conditions because they are clearly specified, and due to that can optimize these best. And write it in the way that describes best what you do, even if `for (int i = 0; i < this->lenght * this->height; i++)` might look less efficient, the compiler might still understand better what you do there then with `for (; adres_this < (this->container + this->lenght * this->height); adres_this++, adres_A++)`.